# If $|r'(t)| = 1$ then the arc length of $r(t)$ from $t=a$ to $t=b$ is $b-a$.

Tags: calculus, vectors

I'm currently taking calculus 3, and I'm having difficulty understanding the following proposition:

*If $|r'(t)| = 1$ then the arc length of $r(t)$ from $t=a$ to $t=b$ is $b-a$*.

The proposition works only when it is equal to $1$? Or does it refer to a constant $c$, so it could be equal to $2$? Also, I'm unsure why the proposition works and can't seem to visualize it.

Is it because it means that the tangent(velocity) vector $|r'(t)|$ is equal to the unit tangent vector?

Also, my professor added a remark: "we say curves that have $|r'(t)| = 1$ are parameterizations of arc length. It is not always practical, but it is always helpful theoretically speaking."

Thank you,

Comment: Intuitively: If you walk at 1m/s for time $t$ seconds, no matter how you change the direction, you will end up walking $t$ metres.

Comment: @Trebor What if |r'(t)| = 2, then you are going at 2m/s for time t seconds and it means that (b-a)*2?

Answer (score 0):

It is a direct consequence of the following theorem:

**Theorem:** Let $(r,\Gamma)$ be a parametrized curve, with $r:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{d}$. If $r\in C^{1}([a,b])$ then $\Gamma$ is rectifiable and $l(\Gamma)=\int_{a}^{b}\parallel r'(t) \parallel dt$.

($l(\Gamma)$ denotes the length of the curve $\Gamma$).

So we can easily conclude that if $\parallel r'(t) \parallel \equiv 1$ $\forall t \in [a,b]$ the arc length of $\Gamma$ from $t=a$ to $t=b$ is equal to $b-a$.

Comment: It might answer why the proposition is true, but it doesn't help me to understand/visualize it. It is a bit too advanced for me what you wrote.